# Assistance building array in PowerShell please

Tags: powershell

I've written some code to import data from logfile.txt and export the results 
with `Export-Csv` to a weapons_date. I'm replicating each line but I'm sure I might be able to do this better, perhaps with an array or loop or something?

I did some basic research but don't fully understand arrays.

```
$TestPath = $null
$sourcefile = "logfile.txt"
$dest = "weapons_"
$date = (Get-Date -Format "%d%M%y-%H%m%s")
$target = $dest+$date+".csv"

if (Test-Path $destinationfile) {Remove-Item $destinationfile}

Get-Content $sourcefile |
    Select-String -Pattern "weapon_sks" |
    Measure-Object -Line |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Weapon -Value SKS -PassThru |
    Export-Csv -Path $target -NoTypeInformation

Get-Content $sourcefile |
    Select-String -Pattern "weapon_rpk" |
    Measure-Object -Line |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Weapon -Value RPK -PassThru |
    Export-Csv -Path $target -NoTypeInformation -Append

#...

[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Parsing Log File complete','Logfile Outcome','OK')
```

I want to build an array to make file much shorter so I can perhaps just read from a string or CSV with list of names?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Should the file content be in an array or in the MessageBox? Can you show what is the content of `logfile.txt` is and what the content of the new file should be?

Comment: Definitely need clarification as to your use case here.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity @Alex_P @M2065

The logfile.txt is the source file which the script reads from, then based on the condition pipes it out to the CSV (I hope I'm explaining this correctly!)

The Logfile.txt line is similar to `L 07/01/2019 - 02:04:18: "player<STEAM_x:x:xxxxxxxx><#Team_Security>" killed "BOT Phil<10><BOT><#Team_Insurgent>" with "weapon_mk46" at (455.822998, 31.914600, 0.031250)`

One line of the csv is `Weapon Lines
AK47 0
usas12auto 0`
If easier I can provide files on OneDrive?

Comment: This doesn't make it much clearer.. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58243833/edit) your question and add examples from the logfile.txt and below that what you want the exported CSV file to look like

Comment: No need to provide a full file. Just add a few lines of the logfile to your question and add what exactly the outcome should look like.